# Windows (or maybe Chrome) "micro" freezes

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, memory, freeze

I'm running Windows 8.1 x64 on a quite decent machine (16GB DDR3 Ram, i7 4770k, Asrock Z87 Pro4, Samsung 830pro). More lately, the feeling of using it became more and more slowly, without really installing much new software, just the regular usage of internet/music/office.

The most annoying thing is surfing in Chrome. I detected that even when I only have three tabs open (two of them attached) my task manager still shows quite many processes:

[image]

And when, for example, I open three tabs at a time, the CPU load in the task manager shows quite a heavy peak. I want to show you one example. I kept Chrome open with the three tabs mentioned above, waited a few seconds until everything was balanced and the load was low, then I opened 5 tabs from the bookmark bar at once. The results can be seen here:

[image]

I've got a few extensions enabled, but not that many, and even more important: not any more then a few weeks ago, when this problem did NOT exist yet.

But the same is happening in a fresh profile, so I think it's not really due to these extensions. I'm running Malwarebytes Anti-Exploit Free but even when disabling the protection, the same result is happening.

The problem is that I guess this high CPU load causes quite a big lag in **using** the browser when surfing. E.g. when typing some keywords into the search bar, google search results will load - and even when I already see the results, it takes let's say 2 seconds until I can click any of the page. And when I open one of the results in a new tab, again the mouse is blocked for 2s before I can open another result in a new tab or go to the new tab...

First I thought there'd be some sort of a problem with my harddisk, e.g. it is getting too slow or something, but it is still alright I think.

[image]

Temps of the cores also look alright.

[image]

I'm still not sure whether the problem is really Chrome itself or the Windows in complete. I mean, **I can feel it in Chrome the most**, but also when opening explorer or some Windows tools, sometimes it hangs for a moment unexpectedly. But this rather occurs more rarely... Just with the normal usage... Does rather feel like a Pentium 4 sometimes :-( Like when starting some tool in admin mode, it sometimes takes 2 seconds to show up the UAC window.

How would you proceed here? Is there any way of **measuring** within Chrome which extension might cause some loads, or what exactly is slowing down the browser? Or is it possible in Windows itself, to check whether there are e.g. way too many numbers of harddisk accesses (write / read), maybe there is some sort of underlying problem..!?

I'll also boot from Ultimate Boot CD to check Prime95 and Memtest86+ to see whether there is a hardware issue.

Thanks for any help!

---

**EDIT**:
Memtest86+ shows fine results, thanks god ;-)
[image]

Comment: Oh well, after further digging in: I couldn't believe it, but after disabling AdBlock Plus and using uBlock now, the whole usage got waaaay more responsive. I'm not quite sure what's the problem here as I've been using ABP since yeaaaars - but maybe there was an update lately which caused much more overhead or anything like  that... I'm still trying to figure out within Windows whether there sometimes are too many write/read accesses in general. I hope I can figure out something here.

Answer (score 2):

You should unload some of the add-ons to troubleshoot this.  Each of those lines represents a plugin or add-on.

Comment: Yes somehow uBlock seems MUCH more memory-efficient then ABP. Or maybe I had some old/bad/broken filters loaded in ABP which caused the issues here, dunno. Now after migrating to ABP it seems so much better. I will still try to figure out whether there is something wrong within Windows itself. Sometimes UAC window takes 3 seconds to display when opening a program in admin-mode even though the Load is nearly idle..